# SSIS 2008 on SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, compatibility

Is there any way to get the benefits of SSIS 2008 (including the performance improvements) while still working with a SQL Server 2005 database?  It seems like it still pulls the data from OLE, so I don't see how it would be a problem.  I'm running the package from the dtproj file, not loaded onto the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no problem using a 2005 or 2000 or even a version 7 DB
However I don't think you can install SSIS 2008 on a box that has SQL Server 2005 on it since you will most likely need to pay for a separate license

Answer (score 1):

I have asked microsoft licensing and installing 2008 components on a 2005 instance can be done at no extra charge.  We plan on doing this for reporting, but still want to install 2005 on the server to do some warm-standby mirroring.

edit:  I assume you would need software assurance (somewhat obvious, but otherwise you would have to pay for the 2008 upgrade anyway.)